# Ruby on Rails: Is it possible to display two variables against with collection_check_boxes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

In my RoR application I am displaying a checkboxes for a user's to select their contacts. This is done through the following line of code:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :firstname, { prompt: "firstname" } %>
```

This only display the contacts' firstname, is it possible to display both firstname and surname?

I have tried the following, but they have not worked.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, { :firstname & " " & :surname }, { prompt: "firstname" } %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, { :firstname :surname }, { prompt: "firstname" } %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :firstname :surname, { prompt: "firstname" } %>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]),:id, :full_name ,{ prompt: "firstname" } %>
```

where in model.rb, add

```
  def full_name
    "#{firstname} #{surname}"
  end
```

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can add instance method in `user` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def fullname
    firstname + surname
  end
end
```

and use here:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :contact_ids, Contact.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), :id, :fullname, { prompt: "firstname" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method in the `Contact` model like this:

```
def full_name
    firstname + " " + surname
end
```